# How can I make Microsoft Outlook 2013 automatically mark a message as read when it is clicked?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Normally, when I click on an unread message in Outlook 2013, the message remains in the unread state until I click on a different message. How can I make it so that it marks as read when I click on the message like Outlook.com webmail?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can enable this with "Reading Pane" option enabled. Go to:

1. File -> Options
2. Mail
3. Under "Outlook Panes" click on "Reading Pane"
4. Set the options to whatever you like.

I have it set to "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" and "Wait 0 seconds before marking item as read". This way as soon as i click on an email it is changed to read.